# Complexity of "discrete-time" SAT

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, lo.logic, temporal-logic

I'm interested in the complexity of deciding satisfiability of the following family of formulae:

$\exists j. I[j(0)] \land \forall t. S[j(t),j(t+1)]$

where:

- $j:\mathbb{N} \to \{0,1\}^n$ has finite support, that is, there exists some $x$ such that $j(l) = 0^n$ for all $l \ge x$.
- $I, S$ are propositional formulae.
- $t$ is a "temporal" variable to be interpreted over the natural numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is PSPACE-complete:

**Membership in PSPACE via a nondeterministic PSPACE algorithm:**

```
verify that S[0^n,0^n] is true
guess j such that I[j]
while(j != 0^n ){
     guess j' such that S[j,j']
     j:=j'
}
```

You can also remark that the threshold $x$ never needs to be more than $2^n$, otherwise you have $j(t)=j(t')$ for some $t<t'\leq x$, and then we could directly jump at time $t$ from $j(t)$ to $j(t'+1)$ and reach the threshold sooner.

**PSPACE-hardness**:

Let $M$ be a PSPACE Turing Machine running in space $p(n)$. A configuration of $M$ is the content of the tape, and the position and state of the reading head. You can encode such a configuration via a list $j$ of $N=k\cdot p(n)$ boolean variables, using a fixed number $k$ of variables per tape cell. This $k$ depends on the alphabet and number of states of $M$: for each cell the $k$ bits tell you the letter in the cell, and whether the reading head is present there in some state $q$. Then, it suffices to have $I[j]$ accept iff $j$ is the initial configuration, and $S[j,j']$ accepts in these three cases: either $j\to j'$ is a valid transition, or $j$ is an accepting configuration and $j'=0^N$, or $j=j'=0^N$.
This way, your instance is satisfiable iff $M$ accepts, so you've encoded an arbitrary PSPACE problem as an instance of your satisfiability problem.

Comment: could you explain how you build $S$ to accept when $j \to j'$ is a valid transition?

Comment: You can do a big disjunction, where each disjunct expresses that a transition $\delta$ is being performed at a position $p$ of the tape. Such a disjunct just needs to say that the variables encoding the positions $p-1,p,p+1$ match the transition $\delta$, and all other variables are identical between $j$ and $j'$. The whole formula has polynomial size, since you have polynomially many possible pairs $(p,\delta)$. The part about other positions being left unchanged can actually be shared between all disjuncts, no need to repeat it.